# Russian language not display proper in PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, fpdf

I am using Codeigniter to generate PDF in russian language using fpdf.

IN that I have pass string like '**Добровольческой Бригады, 19, оф.1**' but it displays in  pdf like '**Ð”Ð3⁄4Ð±Ñ€Ð3⁄4Ð2Ð3⁄4Ð»ÑŒÑ‡ÐμÑ•ÐoÐ3⁄4Ð1 Ð‘Ñ€Ð ̧Ð3Ð°Ð ́Ñ‹, 19, Ð3⁄4Ñ„.1**' .

How can I make it proper?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standard FPDF fonts use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. It is possible to perform a conversion to ISO-8859-1 with `utf8_decode()`: `$str = utf8_decode($str);` But some characters such as Euro won't be translated correctly. If the iconv extension is available, the right way to do it is the following: `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);`

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion but no luck.please check attach screen short in my question. display value like '???????' which you can seen my image.

Comment: Can you please try with `iconv('UTF-8','KOI8-R','Добровольческой Бригады, 19, оф.1');`

Comment: Thanks for your replies but no luck again. my code is:     $str = utf8_decode("Добровольческой Бригады, 19, оф.1:");
$str = iconv('UTF-8','KOI8-R',$str);
$this->fpdf->Cell(80, 5, $str, 1, 1, 'L', true);